# Android Trying to get Public Key from public key byte array: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid point encoding 0x30

Tags: android, security, encryption, openssl, ecdh

I am supposed to receive server public key ("ECDH" , "secp256k1") in HEX format, which is uncompressed (65 bytes), generate my own public key in Android which is in `X.509`format (88 bytes), and then generate a shared secret which must be 32 bytes.
Now when I want to get server public key I ran into this error:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: invalid KeySpec: point not on curve

**The procedure:**
First I produce my own public key, then turn server HEX key into byte array: `serverKey.getBytes()` , then put it in another method below :

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
KeyPairGenerator kpgen =KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
ECGenParameterSpec genspec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
kpgen.initialize(genspec);
KeyPair localKeyPair = kpgen.generateKeyPair();    
ECPublicKey remoteKey = decodeECPublicKey(serverKey.getBytes());
KeyAgreement localKA = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
localKA.init(keyPair.getPrivate());
localKA.doPhase((ECPublicKey) remoteKey, true);
byte[] localSecret = localKA.generateSecret();
```

`decodeECPublicKey` is:

```
public static decodeECPublicKey getPublicKeyFromBytes(byte[] pubKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("secp256k1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
    ECPoint point =  ECPointUtil.decodePoint(params.getCurve(), pubKey);
    ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, params);
    ECPublicKey pk = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
    return pk;
}
```

Which upon execution, produces this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid point encoding 0x30

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Ok. The wrong part was `serverKey.getBytes()` thanks to @Topaco. Now that I have `localSecret` I want to encrypt a `String` with AES-256-CBC algorithm using first 16 bytes of `localSecret` as iv, and second ones as the key.
I have written this code but when I send the result to the server it generates error:

```
public static byte[] enc(byte[] key, String toBeEnc) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);
        byte[] keyByte = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(key, 16, keyByte, 0, keyByte.length);
        Key keyF = new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "AES");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyF, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(toBeEnc.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return enc;
    }
```

Comment: First you use two different curves (secp256k1 and brainpoolp256r1) which is not possible, both sides must apply the same curve. Also, `serverKey.getBytes()` seems to be wrong. If `serverKey` is a hex encoded uncompressed key, it must be hex decoded.

Comment: `brainpoolp256r1` was a typo I edited it. Yes it is hex encoded I will decode it first.

Comment: Currently it still says `serverKey.getBytes()` so you're not really decoding now, are you? I'll vote to close the question as the question and the code don't match.

Comment: @Topaco I corrected `serverKey.getBytes()` in my original code and it worked. Can you take a look at post EDIT?

Comment: This is a new question to be asked in a new post according to SO rules. But in a nutshell: The posted code seems _technically_ to be OK. So you should verify that the implemented logic matches that of the server and check before making a new post: Do both agreements match, is the agreement used directly (or a derivation of it, which is common), do the derivation of IV and key from the agreement match (e.g. alternatively, only the key could be derived and a random IV used), etc.?

Comment: I had no luck. I have `keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded().length` = 144. Should I convert private key same as public key?

Answer (score 0):

Because many people viewed this question, I'm gonna answer it here: Just make yourself comfortable and use OpenSSL library for Android. Our backend used it to generate its key, I used it as well and it works like a charm.